# The use of **.join()** in this particular code

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code is from an UVA. It goes like:

Consider a list (list = []). You can perform the following commands:

```
 insert, print, remove, append, sort, pop, reverse.
```

Initialize your list and read in the value of  followed by  lines of commands where each command will be of the types listed above. Iterate through each command in order and perform the corresponding operation on your list.

**Inputs:**
The first line contains an integer, denoting the number of commands. 
Each line  of the  subsequent lines contains one of the following commands.

**Sample Input**

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print 
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort 
print
pop
reverse
print
```

**Sample Output**

```
[6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]
```

**A neat solution I found is:**

```
n = input()
l = []
for _ in range(n):
    s = raw_input().split()
    cmd = s[0]
    args = s[1:]
    if cmd !="print":
        cmd += " ("+ ",".join(args) +") "
        eval("l."+cmd)
    else:
        print l
```

I don't really understand how the part  `" ("+ ",".join(args) +") "` works. Especially why the `+` in the beginning and at the end. An explanation would be great. Thanks.

Comment: And the `+` operator concatenates strings.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `eval`  If the source of the string is trusted, then it's fine, but it's likely not a good habit to get into. There are better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could you please explain some of such ways? thanks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I get what the `+` signs at the end at start mean. They are adding different strings. I thought, somehow they were "inside" the function or something.

Comment: Inside what function?

Comment: I thought they were part of the " .join " or something. I am new to python and this format of functions `.something()`.

Comment: Ah, those are called methods.

Comment: If you don't understand code that this course is giving you, you should be reading the instructional materials that surely accompanied it. You could also read the documentation and Google for even more resources. Asking a question here should be your last resort, not your first.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'll keep that in mind going forward. Thank you.

Comment: @Rio1210 [here](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/ccccc7c2a15bf000692531d0dc950c4c) is a sketch of the approach that doesn't require `eval`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks a lot for this.  Learnt a lot from this code.

Answer (score 0):

`.split` will divide your your string into an array.  Each space will create a new element, so if you have `"I like food"`, it will become `["I","like","food"]`.  Now we can look at our `.join`. The `.join` is doing the reverse.  So if we were to call `','.join(["I","like","food"])`, we'd get `"I,like,food"`. In your function, we are using `.join` to combine a series of list elements into a series of string arguments, then we invoke `eval` and it executes.

And, `eval` is **not** recommended.  So, instead, we can write a chain for `if` and `elif` statements:

```
inpu = """12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print 
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort 
print
pop
reverse
print"""

li = []

for line in inpu.split("\n"):
    args = line.split()
    if args[0] == "insert":
        li.insert(int(args[1]),int(args[2]))
    elif args[0] == "print":
        print(li)
    elif args[0] == "remove":
        li.remove(int(args[1]))
    elif args[0] == "sort":
        li.sort()
    elif args[0] == "reverse":
        li = li[::-1]
    elif args[0] == "append":
        li.append(int(args[1]))
    elif args[0] == "pop":
        li.pop()
```